# R - Partial string matching subset

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I have a data frame called LeaseDF. I am looking to pull all observations where the Team_Code column is contains the letter "t". The simple code I have is below. Somehow is not returning anything. I have also tried for loops with the grepl function and lapply with grepl to no avail. Thanks.

```
subset <- LeaseDF[grep("^t-", LeaseDF$TEAM_CODE),]
```

Comment: Why did you use the regular expression `"^t-"` if all you want to check is occurrence of the letter “t”?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that with "**pull**" you mean subset?

As you didn't add your data I am giving you my example, where I used package `sqldf`

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('monday','tuesday','wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'))
require(sqldf)
# Select specific values from a column i.e., containing letter "t"
sqldf("select * from df where name LIKE '%t%'")
# And output
     name
1  tuesday
2 thursday
```

Or use `grep`

```
df$name[grep("t", df$name) ]
# And output
[1] tuesday  thursday
Levels: friday monday thursday tuesday wednesday

# OR use ^t if you want beginning of the string
df[grep("^t", df$name), ]
```

Or use `grepl` and you could also exclude non-matching observations

```
df[grepl("t", df$name), , drop = FALSE]
# Output
      name
2  tuesday
4 thursday
```

Comment: Yes I mean subset. Ok this makes sense. Thanks! I ended up using the sqldf package myself. But I was looking for a way to do it without that package.

Comment: I am glad to help.